# Filter content by searching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple divs on my website and need to be able to filter them by searching for their content.

The search should look for the headings in the divs and hide the divs, which headings donot contain the phrase in the search box. Furthermore the searching should be escaped py pressing the ESC key on the keyboard or by pressing a little x button on the right hand side of the search box. The x button should only be shown when the search is in use

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search ..." />
```

My searchbox looks something like this and should filter the divs below.

```
<div>    <h3>Red</h3>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor est</p>    </div>
<div>    <h3>Green</h3>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor est</p>    </div>
<div>    <h3>Blue</h3>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor est</p>    </div>
<div>    <h3>Orange</h3>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor est</p>    </div>
<div>    <h3>Yellow</h3>    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor est</p>    </div>
```

What would be the most ellegant way to solve the Problem, preferably in jQuery or in php?

Comment: As a general best practice, you don't start with the most elegant way. Usually, you start with a really ugly way that works - then you make it elegant. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What have you tried so far? If all your data is within that file, you should use `Jquery/javascript`.

Comment: @Nytrix `JQuery === JavaScript`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Applied the function to work with input change as well.

Allright check this out...basic search filtering. Just add the proper classes to your html, and run this jquery code. Here is a fiddle I just created.

```js
var $searchContainer = $("#search");
var $contentBoxes = $searchContainer.find(".content");
var $searchInput = $searchContainer.find("#search-input");
var $searchBtn = $searchContainer.find("#search-btn");

$searchBtn.on("click", searchContent);
$searchInput.on("input", searchContent);

function searchContent() {
  var userInput;

  //Check if call comes from button or input change
  if ($(this).is(":button")) {
    userInput = $(this).siblings("input").val();
  } else {
    userInput = $(this).val();
  }

  //make the input all lower case to make it compatible for searching
  userInput = userInput.toLowerCase();

  //Loop through all the content to find matches to the user input
  $contentBoxes.each(function() {

    var headerText = $(this).find(".title").text();
    var contentText = $(this).find(".description").text();
    //add the title and content of the contentbox to the searchable content, and make it lower case
    var searchableContent = headerText + " " + contentText;
    searchableContent = searchableContent.toLowerCase();

    //hide content that doesn't match the user input
    if (!searchableContent.includes(userInput)) {
      $(this).hide();
    } else {
      $(this).show();
    }

  });

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search">
  <form>
    <input type="search" id="search-input" placeholder="Search ..." />
    <button id="search-btn" type="button">Search</button>
  </form>


  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="title">Red</h3> 
    <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor est</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="title">Green</h3> 
    <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor est</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="title">Blue</h3> 
    <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor est</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="title">Orange</h3> 
    <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor est</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h3 class="title">Yellow</h3> 
    <p class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor est</p>
  </div>



</div>
```

And here is a fiddle if it's better that way :)
https://jsfiddle.net/9p89034t/22/

Comment: Works pretty well ;)
Is it pssible search while typing, without having to click on the button?

Comment: Yeah, check out the edit, you just had to apply the same function with a small edit to the input on "input" change.